# Java File Class Using Relative Path in Windows 7

Tags: java, file, maven-2, relative-path

I am having some confusing behavior on a Maven2 unit test. The following test code produces different results running in Eclipse vs. Maven2:

```
File f = new File( JUnitConstants.TEST_FILE );
File root = new File( "." );
Log.info( "File Info:" );
Log.info( f.toString() + (f.exists() ? " exists" : " doesn't exist") );
Log.info( f.getAbsoluteFile().toString() + (f.getAbsoluteFile().exists() ? " exists" : " doesn't exist") );
Log.info( root.toString() + (root.exists() ? " exists" : " doesn't exist") );
Log.info( root.getAbsoluteFile().toString() + (root.getAbsoluteFile().exists() ? " exists" : " doesn't exist") );
```

In Eclipse, everything exists and the unit tests runs fine. In maven, the f.exists() method returns false; so it thinks that file doesn't exist! Here is the output from the maven run test:

```
2013-01-10 09:50:51,737 [main] INFO  - File Info:
2013-01-10 09:50:51,737 [main] INFO  - target\test-classes\test\test.img doesn't exist
2013-01-10 09:50:51,737 [main] INFO  - C:\Users\me\code\HEAD\modules\project\target\test-classes\test\test.img exists
2013-01-10 09:50:51,737 [main] INFO  - . exists
2013-01-10 09:50:51,737 [main] INFO  - C:\Users\me\code\HEAD\modules\project\. exists
```

So, the file exists, the root directory is what I expect, but why does Java think the file does not exist, when using relative paths?

I'm on Windows 7, 64-bit; using JDK 1.6_38 32-bit.

Comment: Can you show us the exact value of `JUnitConstants.TEST_FILE`?

Comment: Sure, it is `public static final String TEST_FILE="target/test-classes/test/test.img";` I'll note changing the / to File.separator doesn't appear to make a difference in this case.

Comment: I think it is broken in Maven because of the `target` and `test-classes` parts of the filepath. Try using just `"test/test.img"` as your relative path. Where does this file live in your project structure? I think it should be in `/src/test/resources/` followed by whatever your test's package is. I am not sure if this will work in Eclipse though, I don't use that IDE.

Comment: No. That's not it either. If I remove `target/test-classes` then both the `f` and `f.getAbsoluteFile()` are not found. The file is in the standard, Maven location (`src/test/resources` as `test/test.img`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, I've determined that the problem is the forking of the surefire test process. The maven build runs the tests under a command similar to:

```
cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_38\jre\bin\java" -Djava.library.path=target/test-classes -jar C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\surefirebooter6580985433891892701.jar C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire8381564625923782274tmp C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire2578536694398675625tmp"
```

I can run java with those exact parameters (inside the quotes) from the command line and everything works, but as soon as I fork them to another command window (the cmd.exe /X /C), it fails the same way.

I've solved this by disabling forking in the pom.xml file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Djava.library.path=target/test-classes</argLine>
        <forkMode>never</forkMode>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This still must be something in my system configuration, because other Windows 7 64-bit computers don't have this issue, but turning off forking seems to be a solution.

Comment: Ah ha! I finally stumbled upon the true cause of all these issues: In the registry, there is a setting under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor called Autorun. This was set to change to a specific directory. When Maven runs unit tests, it implements them by running the cmd.exe command, which runs the `cd /Users/cneller` command before starting anything else. No wonder none of the relative-path files were found; they were not relative to my home directory, but rather the directory the cmd.exe was run from.

Answer (score 1):

I've never actually used the `new File(filepath)` constructor in a test. I always use...

```
String filepath = "test/test.img"; // relative to src/test/resources
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filepath);
```

Or if the resource files are in the same package structure as the test(s) that use them, you can use the simpler...

```
String filename = "test.img"; // relative to src/test/resources/package/where/tests/live
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(filepath);
```

This seems to always work in both Maven and in my IDE of coice, [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

For a nice explanation on the code above, see [this blog post](http://fuyun.org/2009/11/how-to-read-input-files-in-maven-junit/).

Comment: Thanks for your help Jesse. I'm going to chalk this one up to my environment for now. The code works normally on Windows XP, Fedora 17, and OS X 10.8, but not not Windows 7. Something is amiss. Regardless, I can get around this by using `InputStream` as you suggest, or just using `getAbsoluteFile()` so for testing, this should be fine.